# Datastore Location in XenApp 5?

Tags: citrix, xenapp

I inherited a Citrix enviorment and I am trying to create some much needed documentation. What XenApp console will direct me to the name of the Datastore in the environment? Where can I find out the name/ IP of the Datastore DB in XenApp 5?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realise this is an old question, but this Citrix Knowledge Centre article may help ...

[CTX105257 - How to Determine Where the IMA Data Store Database is Located](http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX105257)